# LinkedHashMap in java

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I was seeing the source code of `LinkedHashMap` ,when the instance of `LinkedHashMap` is created it first it creates header, and when a new entry is added into the `LinkedHashMap` it adds the particular entry before the header, I am not able to understand these line of code

```
 private void addBefore(Entry<K,V> existingEntry) {
        after  = existingEntry;
        before = existingEntry.before;
        before.after = this;
        after.before = this;
    }
```

what I have understood is that **after** pointer is pointing to the header always as i can see
and **before** pointer is pointing to the entry before **existingEntry**
can anybody explain me this code and how it maintain the pointer **after** and **before**.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is called when you are inserting a new Entry into the List. I guess  it is best explained with an example.

Let's assume you have two entries `A` and `B`, where `A` is before `B`. In this case these Entries have the following values:

```
A.before = B
B.after = A
```

Now you want to insert a new Entry `X` between the two. In this case the method you posted is called for `X`. After its execution you have the following values:

```
A.before = X
X.after = A
X.before = B
B.after = X
```

The method `addBefore()` not only needs to set the `after` and `before` members of the new Entry, it also needs to update the references in the linked members.